# How to refresh the meta tags in h:head?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

In jsf2 when I have PROJECT_STAGE = Production my h:head part is not refreshed. When I change it to Development, then everything works fine. How to force the head part for being refreshed?
The h:head is in template.xhtml.

**template.xhtml:**

```
<h:head>
    <meta name="description" content="#{metaBean.metaDescription}" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="#{metaBean.metaKeywords}" />
</h:head>
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <!-- <param-value>Development</param-value>--> 
    <param-value>Production</param-value> 
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>0</param-value>
</context-param>
```

...Or How to make dynamic meta description in other way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta filter like this

```
public class HtmlMetaFilter implements Filter {

private List<String> metaNames = null;
private List<String> metaValues = null;
private int metaSize = 0;

@Override
public void destroy() {
    // logger.info("html meta filter destroyed.");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse)response;
    for(int i = 0; i < metaSize; i++) {
        res.setHeader(metaNames.get(i), metaValues.get(i));
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    metaNames = Configuration.getInstance().getList("//configuration/web-app/html-meta/name");
    metaValues = Configuration.getInstance().getList("//configuration/web-app/html-meta/value");
    if(metaNames != null && metaValues != null) {
        metaSize = Math.min(metaNames.size(), metaValues.size());
    }
    // logger.info("html meta filter initialized.");
}
}
```

If you want to change it dynamically, then you need to set the different data in init method from your bean file.

Comment: I tried this idea with filter, but it doesn't work. I've put for tests something very simple: res.setHeader("description", "test value for desc"); and it doesn't exist in the output html. The filter is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I've found answer on this post: [title in h:head rendered before render response phase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282140/title-in-hhead-rendered-before-render-response-phase)

It's enough to use event preRenderView and prepare necessary values in it.

Comment: It works for `@RequestScoped` bean, but not for longer scoped bean (for example session scoped).

Comment: Indeed, I have @SessionScoped, thank you for help anyway