# p:ajax listener not updating all values of a List correctly - Primefaces spinner

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 5.1.
I have the following in my JSF page. Note, I'm iterating over a List. So there is many Spinners (more than one).

```
<p:accordionPanel value='#{myBean.spotLst}' var="bspot" multiple="true" > 
<p:tab >
    Price:
    <h:outputText value="#{bspot.price}" >
        <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###.##" type="currency"   
                             minFractionDigits="2"/>                            
    </h:outputText> €

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" >
        <h:outputText value="Anzahl Spots: " />
        <p:spinner id="minMax" value="#{bspot.nbrPP}" min="0" max="30" >
            <p:ajax update="@([id$=updateView])" 
                       listener="#{myBean.updateView}" event="change" />
        </p:spinner>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:tab> 
</p:accordionPanel>   

Full price: 
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.price}" id="updateView" >
<f:convertNumber pattern="###,###.##" type="currency" minFractionDigits="2" />                            
</h:outputText> €
```

and in ManagedBean (Perfoming some calculation of the full price)

```
public void updateView() {
    double pp = 0;
    for (BookedSpot bspot : getSpotLst()) {
       bspot.setPrice(bspot.getPrice() * bspot.getNbrPP());
       pp += bspot.getPrice();
    }
    setPrice(pp);
}
```

Now the problem: let say I have 2 Spinner, price1(of spot1) = 10 and price2 = 30. First, both nbrPP values are zero. After increasing nbrPP1 to value 1, the listener fires and the full price is updated as expected to the value `1*10 + 0*30 = 10`. Now I increase nbrPP2 to value 2. The listener updates the full price to the value `0*10 + 2*30 = 60`. The listener is not taking the new value `1` of nbrPP1 set bevor. 
Why? 
I tried putting `immediate="true"` but then the listener doesn't fire any more.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: The bean is viewscoped.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add *process="@this"* to the p:ajax tag to be sure that the values are applied:

```
<p:spinner id="minMax" value="#{bspot.nbrPP}" min="0" max="30" >
    <p:ajax process="@this" 
            update="@([id$=updateView])" 
            listener="#{myBean.updateView}" event="change" />
</p:spinner>
```

Comment: Ok. Then I would log what is setted in bspot.setNbrPP() and see in the updateView() function if bspots given by getSpotLst() are up to date with the new values.

Comment: I'm already logging this. The function updateView() doesn't update the new values. Even when there are still there on the website.

Comment: I've found the source of the problem. I'm using a preRenderView event in my page and this is also triggered by an ajax partial page rendering. Right now I'm investigating a possible solution.

Comment: I solved the problem. Actually I used a method described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830834/jsf-fevent-prerenderview-is-triggered-by-fajax-calls-and-partial-renders-some). I tried the one with `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()` to prevent my preRenderView to fire again when using ajax and it works fine!