# Can the Flash data be persisted after redirection?

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces, flash-scope

Using JSF 2.1.29

In **list.xhtml**

```
<p:commandLink id="ownerViewLinkId" value="#{petOwner.firstName} #{petOwner.lastName} " 
action="#{ownerAndPetListBean.viewPetOwnerFrmList(petOwner.id,petOwner.userId,0)}"
        onclick="PF('progrees_db').show()"
        oncomplete="PF('progrees_db').hide()"
        style="color:#0080FF;">
</p:commandLink>
```

In **listBean** (viewscoped),

```
public void viewPetOwnerFrmList(String ownerIdStr, String userIdStr,
            String petIdStr) {
    try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("ownerId",ownerIdStr);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("userId",userIdStr);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("petId",petIdStr);

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                    .redirect("/ownerandpets/view");

    } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("FL Warning", e);
    }
}
```

**pretty-config.xml**

```
  <url-mapping id="ownerandpetsview"> 
      <pattern value="/ownerandpets/view" />          
      <view-id value="/WEB-INF/views/ownerAndPet/OwnerAndPetsView.xhtml" />
      <action onPostback="false">#{ownerAndPetViewBean.fillPage}</action> 
  </url-mapping>
```

In **viewbean** (viewscoped),

```
String petIdStr;
String userIdStr;
String ownerIdStr;
String firstName;
//include getters and setters
public void fillPage() {

    petIdStr = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("petId");
    userIdStr = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("userId");
    ownerIdStr = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("ownerId");

    System.out.println(ownerIdStr+" "+userIdStr+" "+petIdStr);
    firstName = getFromDBByOwnerId(ownerIdStr); 
}
```

In **view** page,

```
<h:outputText value="#{ownerAndPetViewBean.firstName}"/>
```

firstName is displayed after redirect.
On refreshing the view page (by pressing f5), the string firstName becomes null and id strings printed in viewBean's fillPage is null.
What i need is on refresh, i need to refetch firstName for which the ids must not be null.
Had gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flash-scope/info)
Anyway to persist the flash data in request?

Tried the below but was not successful :

**1.**

```java
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                    .redirect("/ownerandpets/view?faces-redirect=true");
```

**2.**

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
    .getExternalContext().getFlash().keep("ownerId");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
    .getExternalContext().getFlash().keep("userId");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
    .getExternalContext().getFlash().keep("petId");
```

**3.**

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
    .getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
    .getFlash().setRedirect(true);
```

On Refresh debugging, the ids are there in the flash scope map on watching `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash()` , but the same is not displayed in watching `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("petId");` (see fig 2).

[image: Values in Flash Map on Refresh - Fig 1]
[image: Fig 2]

**Update 1 (Answer):**

As suggested by Xtreme Biker, added preRenderView to the view page.

`<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{ownerAndPetViewBean.fillPage}"/>` .

From the pretty-config.xml, remove or comment

`<action onPostback="false">#{ownerAndPetViewBean.fillPage}</action>`

Put a not postback checking in fillPage method and added flash.keep in managed bean.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().keep("ownerId");
```

The above method will not work with pretty-faces action tag (if used instead of preRenderview) and we will get page with no values.

Comment: Please, add the JSF version/impl which you're using

Comment: I have updated the question.. Using JSF 2.1.29.

Comment: Don't know how Prettyfaces handles its actions. Instead, what I recommend you is to call `ViewBean#fillPage` in a `preRenderView` event in the facelet when you're loading your view (check there if the incoming request is a postback or not, and perform only when it's not). Then, there invoke `flash.keep`, which should do the job you're looking for. Have a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25057753/1199132) to see how to keep them directly from EL, but you could do the same from the managed bean in java code.

Comment: yes..it works when uesd preRenderView..:)

Comment: Wanted to post a loong comment, posted as an answer instead ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prettyfaces action is probably out of the scope of the current flash state. Don't know exactly how the pretty action works, but you need to set `flash.keep` in the same request cycle where the redirection is performed (If using pretty, that's done by a `POST-REDIRECT-GET` pattern).

Anyway, as [the docs example](http://www.ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html/Configuration.html#config.actions) for pretty action shows a `@RequestScoped` bean, don't know its compatibility with the View Scope and with the flash state, consequently. I personally prefer to use the `f:event='preRenderView'` [checking for postbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7778971/1199132) if you still in JSF 2.1. If JSF 2.2, use `f:viewAction`, without having to check for postbacks.

**See also:**

- [How to keep JSF flash scope parameters on page reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011836/how-to-keep-jsf-flash-scope-parameters-on-page-reload)